# Is there a better way to note down changes in an RDS Postgres database than triggers?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, triggers, amazon-rds

In my work we had a project where we developed triggers in RDS oracle and then used AWS lambda code to move data from temporary tables to RDS Postgres. But that whole exercise took a lot of time.

Are there any other methods are there where I can do the same in RDS Postgres and note down all data changes in RDS Oracle (insert, update and delete) and as soon as it happens then write the data to RDS Postgres? I know I can do this using triggers, but it takes a lot of time and it's a lot of technical debt. Are there any other scalable methods where I can do this? Our cloud environment is in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBridge to respond Oracle events (insert, update and delete) with Lambda to process these events.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-cloud-watch-events.html